# Eclipse: I am not able to debug my apps on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

After a fresh installation of Ubuntu 11.10 on my notebook, I'm no longer able to debug any of my projects.

Deploying and starting of my application is working, but every time I try to debug my code the console output looks like this:

```
Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.vidi.playground' on port 8619
Launch error: Failed to connect to remote VM
```

And the device or emulator says:

Waiting for Debugger

I tried out everything I found here, including a fresh installation of Eclipse and the SDK.
My workspace is also a new one and I set up a fresh playground project.

I find out that there is a red bug next to my activity in the devices view in Eclipse and in DDMS too. The error occurs on a real device and on the emulator (I've tried different OS versions too).

Here is what I am using (all the newest version):

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Sun JDK 6
- Eclipse Indigo
- Android SDK 15

Comment: I'm having a related problem on almost the identical setup with Logcat being extremely slow and resource hungry with actual devices. I wonder if your lgocat behaves similarly? See: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4352 if so. Meanwhile, I will try running debugger as well and see if is same as yours.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be programming related. Perhaps http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com would be a better fit, @BenG.

Comment: Whats running on port 8619? It looks like it is not able to get port 8619. During the upgrade it may have installed something that is now running on that port.

Comment: @apesa if the port is already blocked by another application ddms would say something like **Can't bind to local 8619 for debugger**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution for my problem.

The problem is, if you are using a system wide socks-5 proxy, eclipse is trying to reach the debugger through that proxy connection.

Removing this option in my network setting solves the problem for me.